How to calculate the Motor Constant,(Kt) in (Nm/A) and back emf constant(Ke) of PMSM motor to calculate the applied torque
I have a PMSM motor with a verified back EMF of 12.7 Vrms per 1000 RPM.(Measured on an oscilloscope , Phase U w.r.t Phase V)
I know that this is Ke(12.7)
For a PMSM motor kt and ke are essentially the same, but I am having trouble with the unit conversion!
This is how I am doing my calculations:
For calculation purpose, lets assume that the motor speed is 5000 RPM. And the phase current is 10 Amps (RMS)
Applied Torque(Nm) = Kt(Nm/A) * measured phase current(RMS)
To find Kt in Nm/A:
Kt(Nm/A) = Ke * pi/(60 * Speed)
(Is the above conversion correct?)
Converting Motor Speed(RPM) to speed in rad/s, : 5000 * (2*pi/60) = 523.59 rad/s.
Getting the peak value of Back emf : 12.7 * sqrt(2) = 18v
So kt(Nm/A) = 18 * sqrt(2) * pi/(60*523.59) = 0.0025 Nm/A
So applied torque(Nm) = 0.0025 * 10 = 0.025 Nm ??
Is the above, the correct way of calculating Kt?
